can we create matching rules on case object in salesforce service cloud Enterprise Edition so that we can identify duplicate cases?
can we create matching rules on case object in salesforce service cloud Enterprise Edition so that we can identify duplicate cases ? I am unable to see Case object in object dropdown. what may be the reason ?

consider a custom unique external id field - this would block creation of duplicate cases; field could be populated at before save time by a flow

Only supported objects are shown in the dropdown. At the time of this answer, cases are not supported by Duplicate Management. For now, this feature only supports accounts, contacts, leads, and custom objects. You'll want to vote on this Idea.
If you really want to use duplicate management directly, you could create a custom object that is linked to the case, replicate the fields you want to check against in that custom object, automate creating/updating that custom object when a case is created, and then use duplicate management against the custom object. This can be completely automated with a flow, no code required.

Thank you. will consider having a record triggered flow or trigger to update a check box field on case with link to duplicate case so agent can know. does this look ok or we can consider something else.

@Walker A checkbox would probably be okay, as I assume the duplicate would match on the account/contact and subject, or something like that. I just edited in an alternative using Duplicate Management and some automation. This would help identify which other cases are duplicates.

This feature is still an idea you can upvote the idea.
To manage the case duplication you can write a trigger on before insert to check for duplicate cases. Based on specific fields you can write code to check for duplicate cases.

Thank you. will consider having a record triggered flow or trigger to update a check box field on case with link to duplicate case so agent can know. does this look ok or we can consider something else.
